# How can I call javascript funtion in react js to show style correctly with html theme

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

In my react js, I used html theme but the design is not appeared correctly according to html style design,It is shown as normal checkbox.How can I do that and how can I render javascript function switchery theme.

```
 <div id="tab5" className="tab-pane fade">
 <input type="checkbox" data-render="switchery" data-theme="lime" checked /> 
   </div>
```

Comment: where is your `switchery ` class to apply the styles https://github.com/abpetkov/switchery/blob/master/dist/switchery.css ?

Comment: My switchery class and other style class all are including under assets

Comment: the checkbox doesn't seem to have the class !!!

Comment: Am I right ????   <div id="tab5" className="tab-pane fade">
                                    
                                  <input type="checkbox" className="switchery" data-render="switchery" data-theme="lime" checked /> 
                                     </div>   and i put switchery theme code under style.css

Comment: let me know if the answer I posted works.

Answer (score 0):

Add a selector(class or Id) to the input element

```
 <div id="tab5" className="tab-pane fade">
    <input className="js-switch" type="checkbox" data-render="switchery" data-theme="lime" checked /> 
</div>
```

and call Switchery as shown below.

```
var elem = document.querySelector('.js-switch');
var init = new Switchery(elem);
```

You can read the documentation to apply for multiple input elements [here](https://github.com/abpetkov/switchery#multiple-switches)

Here is the working [codepen link](https://codepen.io/cplog/pen/NwXqEP)

And I believe you are loading the switchery css file into your webpage.

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/switchery.css">
</head>
```